# Logic error with Datetime->modify in Symfony entity

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, logic, entity

I have a Symfony entity `Equipment()` . This entity represent an equipment... Which has controls and Control period in days (for an example, 30 day needed betwin each control). 
A control has a Date and I'm trying to display the next needed control Date.

Here is my Equipment Entity :

```
<?php

namespace StockBundle\Entity;

use StockBundle\Entity\EquipmentControle;

/**
 * Equipment
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="stock_equipment")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="StockBundle\Repository\EquipmentRepository")
 */
class Equipment
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EquipmentControle", mappedBy="equipment")
     */
    private $controles;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="control_interval", type="integer", options={"default" : 0})
     */
    private $controlInterval = 0;

    public function getControles()
    {
        return $this->controles;
    }

    public function getControlInterval()
    {
        return $this->controlInterval;
    }

    public function setControles($controles)
    {
        $this->controles = $controles;
    }

    public function setControlInterval($controlInterval)
    {
        $this->controlInterval = $controlInterval;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLastControlDate(){
        $lastControle = null;
        foreach ($this->getControles() as $c){
            if($lastControle == null || $c->getDate() > $lastControle->getDate()){
                $lastControle = $c;
            }
        }
        return $lastControle == null ? null : $lastControle->getDate();
    }

    public function getNextControlDate(){

        if($this->getLastControlDate() == null && $this->getControlInterval() > 0){
            return new \DateTime("NOW");
        }elseif ($this->getLastControlDate() != null && $this->getControlInterval() > 0){
            return $this->getLastControlDate()->modify('+'.$this->getControlInterval().'day');
        }else{
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

I display my last and next control dates this way using twig :

```
{% if e.lastControlDate is not null %}{{ e.lastControlDate|date('d/m/Y') }}{% else %}-{% endif %}

{% if e.nextControlDate is not null %}{{ e.nextControlDate|date('d/m/Y') }}{% else %}-{% endif %}
```

But it seems that the nextControlDate is always twice the supposed date.

I have my last control on the 29/11/2018 and a `$controlInterval` on `10` and get 19/12/2018 for the next control. It is the same when I try to change the controlInterval.

When I display the `nextControlDate` BEFORE the `lastControlDate` I get the same date for control lastControl and nextControl...

Any help please ?

Comment: It's because you're modifying same instance of DateTime object. Take a look at references in PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php and try to change the DateTime object to DateTimeImmutable or clone the object before modifying it

Comment: I know that but the next control is executed after the last control date function. So this is not the problem. Even if you are right, using datetimeImmuable will allow me to use the functions in any order... The real problem is that my nextControlDate is twice as what it should be.

Comment: If you change the `DateTime` to `DateTimeImmutable` it starts work, you'll see :) and why is the interval added twice? Because you're calling the method `nextControlDate` twice ;) firstly in the twig condition and secondly when you're printing the actual date. That's why you should use immutable structures if you can, to avoid these "mysterious" problems ;)

Comment: Oh damn I just understood, thanks you so much, I'll try this tomorrow first thing but I'm sure it will work. (I didn't know about datetimeImmuable before, so thanks for the lesson ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use immuable version of the Datetime so you can use it multiple times without recalculating from the last modification.

```
if ($this->getLastControlDate() != null && $this->getControlInterval() > 0){

    $dateImmuable = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    $dateImmuable->createFromMutable($this->getLastControlDate());

    return $dateImmuable->modify('+'.$this->getControlInterval().'day');
}
```